# What's the proper way of chaining async functions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have an interesting case where I need to do a few queries in MongoDB using Mongoose, but the response is returning before I can complete all of them.

I have two document types, list and item. In one particular call, I need to get all of the lists for a particular user, then iterate over each of them and fetch all of the items and append them to the appropriate list before returning.

```
List.find({'user_id': req.params.user_id}, function(err, docs){
  if (!err) {
    if (docs) {

      var results = [];

      _und.each(docs, function(value, key) {

        var list = value.toObject();
        list.items = [];

        Item.find({'list_id': value._id}, function(err, docs) {
          if (!err) {
            _und.each(docs, function(value, key) { list.items.push(value.toObject()); });
            results.push(list);
          }
          else {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
      });

      res.send(results);
```

(_und is how I've imported underscore.js)

Obviously the issue are the callbacks, and since there's multiple loops I can't return within a callback.

Perhaps this is a case where I would need to get the count in advance and check it on every iteration to decide when to return the results. This doesn't seem elegant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code solution

First of all the issue is with the code. Your sending the results before the Item.find queries finish. You can fix this quite easily

```
var count = docs.length + 1;
next()
_und.each(docs, function(value, key) {

    var list = value.toObject();
    list.items = [];

    Item.find({
        'list_id': value._id
    }, function(err, docs) {
        if (!err) {
            _und.each(docs, function(value, key) {
                list.items.push(value.toObject());
            });
            // push asynchronous
            results.push(list);
            next()
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});

function next() {
    --count === 0 && finish()
}

function finish() {
    res.send(results)
}​
```

The easiest way is reference counting, you default count to the number of documents. Then every time your finished getting an item you call `next` and decrement the count by one.

Once your finished getting all items your count should be zero. Note that we do `.length + 1` and call `next` immediately. This gaurds against the the case where there are no documents, which would otherwise do nothing.

### Database solution

The best solution is to use mongo correctly. You should not be doing what is effectively a join in your code, it's slow and inefficient as hell. You should have a nested document and denormalize your list.

so `list.items = [Item, Item, ...]`

As a further aside, avoid mongoose, it's inefficient, use the native mongo driver.

Answer (score 1):

I use with this module:
https://github.com/caolan/async